# Exim: use /etc/hosts to resolve domain names

Tags: dns, hosts, smtp, exim

I have just installed `exim4`, and my `/etc/hosts` file looks like this:

```
127.0.0.1     localhost
127.0.1.1     mycomputer
192.168.100.5 rpi.mydomain.com
```

However, when I run `exim -bt john@rpi.mydomain.com` to test deliverability, it says:

```
R: dnslookup for john@rpi.mydomain.com
john@rpi.mydomain.com is undeliverable
```

It appears that Exim is not using the entries in `/etc/hosts` to resolve domain name. To fix the problem, I added this to `/etc/exim4/conf.d/router/200_exim4-config_primary` before all other router entries:

```
mycustomlookup:
  debug_print = "R: mycustomlookup for $local_part@$domain"
  driver = manualroute
  transport = remote_smtp
  route_list=rpi.mydomain.com 192.168.100.5
```

Problem solved. `exim -bt john@rpi.mydomain.com`:

```
R: mycustomlookup for john@rpi.mydomain.com
user@rpi.mydomain.com
  router = mycustomlookup, transport = remote_smtp
  host 192.168.100.5 [192.168.100.5]
```

The problem now is that I don't want to have to manually edit the Exim configuration every time I change the entries in `/etc/hosts`. Is there a way to make Exim use `/etc/hosts` to resolve domain names?

Comment: Cross-posted: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/484129/exim-does-not-use-etc-hosts

Comment: So did that solution not work?